# Coherence of Facial Features in an Antarctic Race

Tags: biology, humans, anatomy, skeletons

I am currently thinking of an Asian-descended race/type of humans who want from the Americas then were expulsed to an agriculturally viable Antarctica by what we know today as the Native Americans, I already thought of their facial features,

*Epicanthic folds, flatter brow ridge (eyebrow bone less protruding than caucasoid, comparable to east asian), large nasal cavity with wide nose, wide but flat cheekbones, narrow and often oblong face, projecting mid-face (upper-jaw and nose), East Asian-type jaw with slightly recessive chin, average facial fat compared to Caucasoid (stocky bodies as a reference)*

My question is, could these features co-occur if such evolution was possible in the first place?

Comment: I cannot make a mental picture of "non-slanted eyes with epicanthic folds". Epicanthic folds are what gives the impression of slanted eyes.

Comment: @AlexP Well I supposed that slanted eyes mean upturned eyes with or without folds so yeah that's what I thought

Comment: In that case nobody has slanted eyes. The eyes of people from East Asia appear slanted because of the epicanthic folds. But epicanthic folds can and do occur occasionally in all human populations, they are not strictly specific to East Asians; for example, here is [a Swede with epicanthic folds](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jens_Byggmark_Schladming_2008.jpg) -- note how his eyes give the same impression.

Comment: @AlexP okay i never have thought of it that way.

Answer (score 2):

## Yeah Sure

Your features are just combinations of facial features of existing peoples. This sort of thing does not effect survival rates. They are essentially random. Epicanthic folds have no practical benefit to Pericanthic folds, for example they catch more sunlight at the specific angle determined by the user's racial latitude. No they don't do that. That would be silly.

Could people migrating from Asia evolve this particular set of features? Sure they could. If you go back far enough, you can evolve any set of features you want. All humans come from the same place and we are exactly as varied in terms of facial features, as we are varied in terms of facial features.

What the heck is "flatter brow ridge" anyway? Flatter than what? Flatter than an orange? Flatter than the ocean?

Comment: Changed it. I actually meant that the brow ridge is flatter than that of caucasoids of Europe, comparable to east asians